# Menu dropdown from hover to click

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, hover, click

how can I change the dropdown menu from hover to click? My website is [www.afdigitale.it](http://www.afdigitale.it) and now the menu opens the submenu on hover

Comment: Currently when clicking on the top-level links user is being redirected to another page that matches that top-level link. What's the expected behavior for those links if you were to change it to `on click`?

For example, how would I acess https://www.afdigitale.it/category/tendenze/ that currently is accessible by clicking on the TENDENZE link in the main navigation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Before posting a question, it is expected that you have ***researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked for **Herald theme** menu setting from the web if any option available from Theme option setting area. I didn't get any thing from the web.

You can check in your **theme options menu setting area** if any option is there for clicking or on hovering may be or You can do below things if not.

First of all, you need to remove your css for on hover opening sub menu.

This is your css on hover in your Herald theme **min.css**

```
.herald-menu ul li:focus>ul, .herald-menu ul li:hover>ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You need to remove **opacity** from this one.

After that, You can set jquery to open your submenu like:

```
 $("#menu-af-digitale-menu li.herald-mega-menu").click(function() {
    var menu_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(menu_id + 'ul.sub-menu').toggle("slow");
 });
```

Or something else for setting animation as your requirement in jquery.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.